# WAL files not being deleted and pg_drop_replication_slot('barman') causes [55000] ERROR: replication slots can only be used if wal_level > = archive

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, barman

My database has stopped deleting WAL files and `pg_xlog` grows to eventually take all my disk space.  I have to use `pg_controldata` and `pg_archivecleanup` to delete them manually.

I'm almost certain it's to do with my tinkering with replication, but I thought I removed it, and the only remnant of that I can see is the replication slot, but when I try to remove it: `pg_drop_replication_slot('barman') causes [55000] ERROR: replication slots can only be used if wal_level > = archive`.  Which I find strange because I'm trying to remove it, not use it.

`$ barman list-server` shows nothing

`SHOW wal_level minimal`

`SHOW archive_command (disabled)`

```
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots
barman,,physical,,,false,,,,23/DF000000
```

`SHOW server_version 9.5.14`

My postgresql.conf is absent of all WAL settings except `max_replication_slots = 1`, which I tried to set to `0`, but the database will not start if I do.

How can I remove my replication slot, or otherwise troubleshoot postgres not deleting its WAL files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "wal_level" back to "archive", and restart.  Then drop the slot.  Then if you don't want leave it at "archive", set it back to "minimal" again, set max_replication_slots to 0, and restart again.

> Which I find strange because I'm trying to remove it, not use it.

Removing a slot requires access to the slot machinery.  It is a form of "use".

Comment: As soon as I did this pg_xlog cleared 10GB off the disk, thanks.